# Entity Framework 6 error serverversion : (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)customerOrderContext.Database.Connection).ServerVersion

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I am implementing a web api that will fetch data using entity framework 6. I am using Sql Server 2014 and visual studio 2015.While debugging the the code in the CustomerDao class I am seeing an exception in the customerOrderContext object though I can see the records in the customer object. However after the using block executes I cant see any records.

((System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)customerOrderContext.Database.Connection).ServerVersion

**CustomerDao**

```
using (var customerOrderContext = new Entities())
                {
                    return (from customer in customerOrderContext.Customers

                            select new CustomerOrder.BusinessObjects.Customers
                            {
                                Id = customer.Id,
                                FirstName = customer.FirstName,
                                LastName = customer.LastName,
                                Address = customer.Address,
                                City = customer.City,
                                Email = customer.Email,
                                Gender = customer.Gender,
                                State = customer.State,
                                Zip = customer.Zip
                            }).ToList();
                }
```

The connection string in the config file is as follows

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EF.CustomerOrderContext.csdl|res://*/EF.CustomerOrderContext.ssdl|res://*/EF.CustomerOrderContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Tom-PC\MSSQLSERVER2014;initial catalog=Ransang;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**The context class is follows**

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities()
        : base("name=Entities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }

    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

**CustomProvider.cs**

```
  public IEnumerable<BusinessObjects.Customers> GetAllCustomers()
        {
            IList<BusinessObjects.Customers> customerCollection = new List<BusinessObjects.Customers>();
            dataAccess.CustomerDao.GetAllCustomers();
            return customerCollection;
        }
```

Comment: Do you receive any exception? *(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)customerOrderContext.Database.Connection).ServerVersion* doesn't seem to be an exception message. Where did you see that?

Comment: While debugging the the code in the CustomerDao class I am seeing an exception in the customerOrderContext object though I can see the records in the customer object. However after the using block executes I cant see any records. I think there is some issue with establishing the connection and hence cant get the data to the Ui

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: Cant see any exception message as such as the application runs without a breaking error. I only  see  the message I mentioned above while debugging

Comment: It's unclear where/how do you see that. Please add a picture from what you see.

Comment: Also after the using block the context is disposed, you should look in the variable which keeps the result of your function. For example I suppose the code is written in a `GetCustomers` method and used this way `var list = Customers();` so what's the value of `list` after executing the code?

Comment: I have updated the post with the image

Comment: I see, what's the result of calling the `GetAllCustomers` method?

Comment: I have updated the post with GetAllCustomers method. It count is zero. No records

Comment: The exception is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.serverversion(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) *The connection is closed.* There is no problem with this.

Comment: Thank for the feedback, you also have my vote :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exception is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.serverversion?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and it's because the connection is closed. There is no problem with this.

But obviously you get empty result because you didn't use the result, you are just returning `new List<BusinessObjects.Customers>()` in your method:

```
public IEnumerable<BusinessObjects.Customers> GetAllCustomers()
{
    IList<BusinessObjects.Customers> customerCollection = 
        new List<BusinessObjects.Customers>(); // ← An empty list
    dataAccess.CustomerDao.GetAllCustomers();  // ← Just executed but didn't use anywhere
    return customerCollection;                 // ← The empty list you created at first
}
```

You need to `return dataAccess.CustomerDao.GetAllCustomers();`: